# Multiple levels with theninclude not returning all rows unless I query the detail

Tags: c#, linq

I'm using .net core 2.0 (I know) and I've got nested data I'm pulling from sql.

The weird thing is that some of the data isn't showing up unless I explicitly search for it.

```
var record = db.Records
               .Include(x => x.ParentLabels)
               .Include(x => x.TopChildren)
               .ThenInclude(x => x.LevelTwoChildren)
               .ThenInclude(x => x.LevelThreeChildren)
               .ThenInclude(x => x.LevelTwoChildren.LevelTwoLabels)
               .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id.Equals(id));
```

The weird thing is that some of the LevelTwoChildren.Labels data does not show up, UNLESS I add the following:

```
var t = record.TopChildren.FirstOrDefault();
var tt = t.LevelTwoChildren.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id.Equals(id2));
```

I've tried doing a foreach through all the record levels but that doesn't help.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can't answer this without seeing the classes. I wonder if this reflects your real code close enough. Esp. the last `ThenInclude` looks weird, like a back navigation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess it is happening because of `.ThenInclude(x => x.LevelTwoChildren.LevelTwoLabels)`. `Include` statements should include one property at a time. What you should do is:

```
var record = db.Records
              .Include(x => x.ParentLabels)
              .Include(x => x.TopChildren)
                .ThenInclude(x => x.LevelTwoChildren)
                  .ThenInclude(x => x.LevelThreeChildren)
              .Include(x => x.TopChildren)
                .ThenInclude(x => x.LevelTwoChildren)
                  .ThenInclude(x => x.LevelTwoLabels)
              .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id.Equals(id));
```

Comment: Note for future readers that "should only include one property at a time" is not necessarily true in all cases. Ctrl-F for `blog.Owner.AuthoredPosts` on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager

Comment: Sorry I didn't get back to this sooner.  Had some [more] urgent stuff come up.  I didn't try this yet but it sounds like it's what I need to fix the issue.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, solved the issue I had too. Looking a the generated sql statement it looks to do what's expected